# Problem with perpendiculars and its generalization

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, analytic-geometry

Here is a geogebra file that I did: https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/vkteyrf2

- $ABC$ is a triangle
- $A_1 \in BC$
- $B_1 \in AC$
- $C_1 \in AB$
- $M \in BC$ is a moving point
  from which I drew paralells to each side of the triangle. The parallel that I drew from $M$ intersects the $AB$ side in point $M_1$ after that from this new $M_1$ point I drew a parallel with $C_1B_1$ and I got a new intersection point let's say $M2$ I repeated this for 5 times and the construction closed.

[image]

From what I can tell this construction will become closed if $A_1,B_1,C_1$ are midpoints, how can I prove this and does this construction work for any polygons?

I appreciate any tips or help regarding this problem!

Comment: "does this construction work for any polygons?" You have described the construction specifically for a triangle. What would "this construction" look like for a square?

Comment: @DavidK https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/se58hjbd

Comment: If I understand your construction correctly, then my own Geogebra sketch suggests that $A_1$, $B_1$, $C_1$ need not be midpoints. Rather, all that's required is for $\overleftrightarrow{AA_1}$, $\overleftrightarrow{BB_1}$, $\overleftrightarrow{CC_1}$ to meet at a point; so, their relative positions are governed by [Ceva's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem). (In the midpoints case, the common point is, of course, the centroid.)

Comment: BTW: The triangle result works trivially when $A_1$, $B_1$, $C_1$ are collinear; ie, when their relative positions are governed by [Menelaus' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem).